# Why I have to write std::cin after including <iostream>?

Tags: c++, namespaces

As far as I know, `<iostream>` header contains everything needed for input/output. But why we again write `std::` namespace before `cin` like `std::cin>>var;`?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int var;
    std::cin>>var;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the object is defined in a [namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace). That's how C++ works.

Comment: Because `cin` is in the `std` namespace.

Comment: Did you use `turbo c++` in the past?

Comment: No. I write in vim and compile and run from a terminal.

Comment: you dont **have** to (see answers) but consider that code is way more often read than written. When I see a `std::` in front of something, then I am happy, because I know the chances to find a bug inside are extremely less compared to anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why we again write `std::` namespace before `cin` like `std::cin>>var;`

It is a protection. This protects **you**. `<iostream>` and other standard includes define a lot (a *LOT*) of identifiers having really common names, e.g. `sort`, `swap`, `list`, `transform`, etc.

Without that protection, all those words would have to be reserved for the implementation. You don't want that.

Answer (score 4):

The `<iostream>` header defines the variable `cin` inside the namespace `std`.

If you want to use it without prefixing the namespace, then you can use

```
using namespace std;
```

after including the header file, but then please read [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

As a compromise you can do

```
using std::cin;
```

to only pull in `std::cin` itself into the current scope and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Because every mechanism supplied by standard wrapped up by `std` namespace. In your case, it's I/O object `cin`.

You can skip entering `std::` every time by placing `using namespace std` (bad case see: [Using namespace std considired bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)) or by placing `using std::cin` to use only one class (object) of the namespace.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 thank you! I've fixed it in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you're looking for a person named John in a building. Finding the right John may be difficult since there may be more than one John in the building. It would be so much easier if you knew which room the right John is currently in.

In the same way, namespaces in C++ help us identify the right artifact being referred to. Think of `cin` as John and the namespace `std` as the room in the building. By using `std::cin`, we know that we're referring to the `cin` that is defined in the `std` namespace and not some other namespace.